# possible bug: pandas trying to fill int column with floats

Tags: python, pandas

In this example:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]: 
   a    b
0  1  1.1
1  2  2.2
2  1  3.3
3  2  4.4

In [2]: df['c'] = 0

In [2]: df.c[df.a == 1] = df.b[df.a == 1]

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   a    b                    c
0  1  1.1  4607632778762754458
1  2  2.2                    0
2  1  3.3  4614613358185178726
3  2  4.4                    0
```

It seems like the resulting behavior is confusing. I know that the problem is that I have initialized 'c' as an int column. If, instead, I use `df['c'] = 0.` then everything works fine. So I get why my example doesn't work. It just seems like there could be a more useful result or at least an error message rather than a seemingly random large number. Definitely a nice to have, rather than need to have.

Comment: What version are you on?  Although you probably shouldn't be doing assignments chained like that, I just tried on 0.13.1 and got the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are chain indexing, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy).

Use:

```
df.loc[df.a==1,'c'] = df['b']
```

Comment: The amazing thing is that the OP's original assignment *does* work in 0.14!